# Can I get breeze.js validation errors without sending the transaction to the server

Tags: validation, breeze

I know as part of SaveChanges breeze will run the validation rules, and if valid will then send the transaction to the server.  I would like to have breeze perform its validations (that it got from the metadata), and then I would like to perform some additional validations before the transaction is sent (more complex, value-based validations like date range, number range, etc).   My goal is to have the metadata validations combined with my custom validations so that any errors can be presented to the user all together.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs -

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation

> Automatic validation The Breeze EntityManager can validate an entity
>   in cache at four predetermined times:
>
> the entity enters cache as a result of a query an entity is added or
>   attached to the EntityManager an entity property value is changed an
>   entity is about to be saved The manager’s ValidationOptions determines
>   whether the manager will or will not validate at those times. The
>   default options are:
>
> Option
>
> Default
>
> validateOnQuery
>
> false
>
> validateOnAttach
>
> true
>
> validateOnPropertyChange
>
> true
>
> validateOnSave
>
> true

```
// copy options, changing only "validateOnAttach"
var valOpts = em.validationOptions.using({ validateOnAttach: false });

// reset manager's options
manager.setProperties({ validationOptions: valOpts });
```

Comment: So if I wanted to manually simulate what breeze does automatically on a "save", I would have to iterate through each entity and call entity.validateEntity()?  I think doing that will populate the error collection, right? Then I can do my external validations and combine the error collections from each process.  If no errors, than i call SaveChanges.  And I can turn off validateOnSave since I've already done the validations manually.

Comment: I am assuming that currently your validation logic is only evaluated when saving (validateOnSave) if you override this value with validateOnPropertyChange: true the validation should occur at the point of change, so the error collection should contain that entity.  You could also subscribe to the change and do an entity.validateEntity() whenever it's value changes, it's all up to what works best in your application

Comment: I only want to do the validation at 1 time as a batch (before the save) not on every change.  The difference is that if there are no errors, I don't want to send the changes, since I have more validations to do outside of what breeze does automatically.  What I'm looking for is a way to separate the batch validations that are done as part of "validateOnSave", and sending the transactions to the backend if there are no errors.   There may be other options.  I may look to see the exact logic that prevents the manager from calling SaveChanges, and maybe manipulate that.